# CKEditor Raw data to controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using CKeditor in MVC 3 app.

Right now i am in need of saving text with HTML tags to DB, problem is that Ckeditors GetData() method returns raw format of data (http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData)

I need a way to make that raw format to normal string with Html tags

**View :**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>TextEditionViewModel</legend>


        @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Id, Model.Texts)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            @Html.TextAreaFor((model => model.Text), new { @Id = "editor1" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
            </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">

            var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
            var url = '@Url.Action("EditText1", "Admin")';
            var data = { CommentText: editor_data };

            function Save() {
               alert(editor_data);
                $.post(url, { CommentText: editor_data }, function (result) {

                });

            };

            $('#Id').change(function () {
                var selectedText = $(this).val();
                if (selectedText != null && selectedText != '') {
                    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Text","Admin")', { Id: selectedText }, function (text) {
                        CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(text);

                    });

                }
            });
</script>
    </fieldset>
     <p>
            <input type="button" value="Save"  onclick="Save()"/>
        </p>
}
```

If editor_data is set to Normal "Text" string everything works!

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult EditText1(String CommentText)
    {

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decorate your controller action with the [`[ValidateInput]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx) attribute to allow POSTing HTML tags which is not authorized by ASP.NET by default:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult EditText1(string commentText)
{
    return null;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

The problem is related to the fact that the editor_data variable is not accessible in the `Save` method.

You could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Save() {
        var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
        var url = '@Url.Action("EditText1", "Admin")';
        var data = { CommentText: editor_data };
        $.post(url, data, function (result) {

        });
    }

    ...
</script>
```

Comment: problem is that if i say alert(editor_data), popup returns "", if i alert(CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData()), it returns the right string, but commentText in controller is still empty. Problem is raw formati gues

Comment: @Timsen, is the `EditText1` controller action executed asynchronously or is it just a normal form submit? You may try returning false from the `onclick` handler to avoid the default action.

Comment: its just a button which call controller action. if i set editor_data to Normal "Text" string everything works ok.  how do i return false onclick?

Comment: @Timsen, like this: `onclick="Save(); return false;"`.

Comment: Still same... i cant find anywhere which parameter CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData() returns...

Comment: figured it out.... Apparently u cant create variable data... u have to call directly like this:  $.post(url, { commentText: CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData() }, function () {